# MDM - Enterprise iOS app: removing selected contacts and calendar events remotely after app uninstall or deletion

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, mdm

We have an enterprise app that adds contacts and calendar events from our server to native iOS addressbook and calendar.
When we have all those contacts/calendar events on our server, how it is possible for us to remove those specific contacts/calendar events from device's **Contacts and Calendar** app after the app is deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) There is no hook to execute any code on app uninstall.

So, your app can't do that.

b) MDM doesn't have a functionality to manage any content.

You can't remove or add any contacts or events through it.

One crazy idea for you. Have you consider to provide IMAP or Exchange service and instead of adding contacts to existing address book? This way you can create them through this service?

If device is managed and IMAP and Exchange account was installed through MDM then you can remove it through MDM (which will remove address book and calendar entries).

Comment: thanks for the response and for the crazy workaround... though it doesn't fit to my application's need. thanks anyways :)